# adding pitch and yaw support to my shaders

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

I try to add depth, pitch and yaw support to my shaders.

Here is my code. It works, but the value of z has no effect. May it be 0 or 1 or anything in between, there is no visible change. So, no depth.

All examples I find use matrices to calculate rotations. I prefer calculating all vertices and textures coordinates myself.

```
    m4 = twgl.m4;

    _webgl.vertex_shader = `
        attribute vec4 position;
        attribute vec2 texcoord;
        uniform vec4 u_resolution;

        varying vec3 v_texcoord;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = position ;
            v_texcoord = vec3(texcoord.xy, 1) ;
        }
    `;

    _webgl.fragment_shader = `
        precision mediump float ;

        varying vec3 v_texcoord ;
        uniform sampler2D tex ;
        uniform float alpha ;

        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2DProj( tex , v_texcoord );
            gl_FragColor.a *= alpha ;
            gl_FragColor.rgb *= alpha ;
        }
    `;

    gl_.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo( gl , [_webgl.vertex_shader,_webgl.fragment_shader] );
    gl_.program = gl_.programInfo.program ;
    gl.useProgram( gl_.program );

    gl.disable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.blendFunc( gl.SRC_ALPHA , gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    gl.blendFunc( gl.ONE , gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    gl.enable( gl.BLEND ) ;
    gl_.resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( gl_.program , "u_resolution" );
    _webgl.webglalpha = gl.getUniformLocation( gl_.program , "alpha" );
    gl.uniform1f( _webgl.webglalpha, 1 );
    _webgl.current_opacity = 1 ;

    gl_.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation( gl_.program , "position" );
    gl_.texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation( gl_.program , "texcoord" );
    gl_.posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl_.texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( gl_.positionLocation );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , gl_.posBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( gl_.positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( gl_.texcoordLocation );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_.texcoordBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( gl_.texcoordLocation , 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
```

During rendering, for every picture visible onscreen, I push xyz coordinates for the vertices in a *_webgl_draw__position* array, and xy of the texture in a *_webgl_draw__texcoord* array.

To calculate coordinates, for each object "e", I do this :
( cam is current camera )
( I do not yet calculate z. I just set z manually to other values than 0 to try before I go on adding maths for yaw and pitch rotations. )

```
e.x_relative_to_camera = e.x - cam.x ;
e.y_relative_to_camera = e.y - cam.y ;
e.z_relative_to_camera = e.z - cam.z ;
e.distance = get_distance_between_points_3d( cam.x , cam.y , cam.z , e.x , e.y , e.z ) ;

e.angle_from_camera_on_xz = get_angle_from_points( cam.x , cam.z , e.x_relative_to_camera , e.z_relative_to_camera )-90 ;
e.angle_from_view_xz = _difference_between_angles_( cam.angle_left_right , e.angle_from_camera_on_xz );
e.x_on_screen = (e.angle_from_view_xz/(cam.FOV/2)) * half_of_game_width ;

e.angle_from_camera_on_yz = get_angle_from_points( cam.y , cam.z , e.y_relative_to_camera , e.z_relative_to_camera )-90 ;
e.angle_from_view_yz = _difference_entre_angles_( cam.angle_top_bottom , e.angle_from_camera_on_yz );
e.y_on_screen = (e.angle_from_view_yz/(cam.FOV/2)) * half_of_game_width ;

e.scaling_on_screen = cam.distance_at_which_scaling_is_1 / e.z_relative_to_camera ;
```

For example, it works with this quad :
-0.13199636340141296 , -0.21341681480407715 , 0
0.13605406880378723 , -0.21341681480407715 , 0
-0.13199636340141296 , -0.6469348073005676 , 0
-0.13199636340141296 , -0.6469348073005676 , 0
0.13605406880378723 , -0.21341681480407715 , 0
0.13605406880378723 , -0.6469348073005676 , 0

Then, at the end, it renders it all at once :

```
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , gl_.posBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, _webgl_draw__position , gl.STATIC_DRAW );

gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_.texcoordBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, _webgl_draw__texcoord , gl.STATIC_DRAW );

gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, _webgl_draw__position.length/3 );
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: There appear to be some uniforms in your vertex shader that aren't used. Is there a reason for that? Beyond that it seems hard to answer the question because the math you're using isn't available to us. I know you said you're sure the values are correct, but you wouldn't be the first person to be sure about something like that yet be mistaken. In any case, you could try submitting some simple geometry in NDC space with non-zero z values and see if you can narrow the problem down that way.

Comment: Oops, yes, these are relics of my tries.

Comment: Even geniuses do mistakes so of course I could do. But I manually checked the values, that it why I am sure. I do not show the calculation code because it calls functions which I would have to show too, so it would be big, mixed with game's stuff, so I hoped I would not have to write a short, clean version to show here. But basically it is just simple trigonometry anyway.

Comment: Starting from a picture on two triangles, at z=0, I changed the z of the vertices, to try. Actually it works up to z=1, with no visible difference from z=0. Then as soon as z is bigger than 1, the picture totally disappear. My values are in pixel by the way, not in clipspace.

Comment: I understand there may be too much math to post comfortably, but I suspect that's where the issue is (or at least that there's a conceptual disconnect somewhere). Your values being in 'pixels' rather than clip space doesn't necessarily make sense, depending. In any case, relevant questions would be: Is your projection orthographic or perspective? And what are the _w_ values of your vertex positions? If you're unable to narrow it down, you could transform some simple geometry (e.g. a quad) and post the original and transformed vertex positions here.

Comment: Oh, first mistake, I was pretty sure that my coordinates were in pixel, and actually they are in clipspace... I do the conversion elsewhere... I am updating the question.

Comment: The projection is perspective. I do not understand what the w value is supposed to be... I seem to remember seeing such a "w" in some shaders examples but I did not understand what it was, this is probably something I am missing.

Comment: Just curious, why not use a matrix or matrices in the shader instead of doing the per vertex math in JavaScript. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and the following 3 articles. What is the point of doing in JavaScript expect because you want it to be slow? In any case you need to show the math you're using for the vertices. Without that your quesiton is impossible to answer.

Comment: Maybe you'll find [this example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/3d-in-canvas.html) useful. It does all the math in JavaScript to generate 2D lines. It comes from [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-vs-3d-library.html)

Comment: Generally speaking, your _w_ coordinates will have to be sensible in order for the output to be what you expect. Standard projection matrix formulations will take care of this for you. As alluded to above, performing the transformations in the vertex shader will likely be more performant, but either way, you'll need to set up the transforms correctly in order to get sensible results. Again, there's currently not enough information available here to comment on the details.

Comment: @gman: I like to understand what goes on. I tried several time to understand matrices but they are still too obscure. Also, for one of the game idea I am working on at the moment, I need to dynamically set the vertices for a short road and apply a looping texture on them. I feel like matrices are not suitable for this and setting vertices by myself is more suitable. I will read that.

Comment: "I feel like matrices are not suitable for this and setting vertices by myself is more suitable." Irrespective of whatever else you're doing, matrices are still likely to be the most straightforward way to apply e.g. view and projection transforms. It's not all or nothing - you can both use matrices and work with vertex data directly as needed.

Comment: [The article linked](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and the preceeding 3 articles try to explain matrices in super simple terms.

Comment: I did add how I calculate coordinates. (I may post the functions if necesary but this may be big.)  I will read it all and hope that at last I understand.

Comment: Thank you guys. What I was missing in my vertex shader to have depth was : `gl_Position = vec4( position.xyz , 1.0 + position.z );` Right?  Now I will be trying to replace my calculations with matrix, for at last it starts to make sense to me, but that is another story.